# Showing a box below an image when mouse over moves also elements on item right

Tags: jquery, css, image, popup, hover

My Goal: i want to create an horizontal list of images. when mouse is over a picture a description appears below the hovered image (in a box with same width but height depending on the text). each description depends on the image

Problem: whit the attached solution, the description appears but it moves also the images on its right.

here is the code.

html

```
<ul id="list-icons">
    <li>
       <img src="" class="icon" />
       <p class="popup">Test</p>
    </li>
      <li>
       <img src="" class="icon" />
       <p class="popup">Test2</p>

    </li>
</ul>
```

jquery

```
<script>
$(".icon").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).next(".popup").slideToggle();
  });
</script>
```

css

```
#list-icons li
{
  display:inline-block;
}

.icon {  
border: 1px solid #aaa;  
width:100px;
height:100px;
}  
.popup{
display:none;
width:100px;
}
```

where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the css as below,

1. Added `width: 100px` to the `li` instead of adding it to `p` tag. And the `width: 100px` on `img` tag will not be applied.
2. Added `vertical-align: top` to make the image stay on top when the description is shown below.

**CSS:**

```
#list-icons li
{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;  
  width:100px;
}
.icon {  
  border: 1px solid #aaa; 
  height:100px;
}  
.popup{
  display:none;
  width:100px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/E5zJM/3/)

Comment: don't just copy my answer... I realized you cited me, but you should not do that...

Comment: @Neal Actually added other css styles + `:hover` and `:hover` was initially posted in your answer and that it is why i added your post. Probably the DEMO code has the complete css.. didn't wanted to duplicate it.. Thank you, I think I should update it posting just what I had.

Answer (score 1):

Try with no javascript at all:

Add this to your css:

```
#list-icons li:hover .popup
{
  display:block;
}​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/E5zJM/

Comment: this has the same problem as mine. 
i would like to have the images stick on their places and the text poping up below them